# Run nodejs result in browser

Tags: node.js, express, nodemon

I am new in nodejs,In server (using ssh) i installed node (expressjs) and npm on server successfully,
In app.js i put following code

```
    var express = require('express');
    var app = express();

    app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send('<html><body><h1>Hello World</h1></body></html>');
    });

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
console.log('Node server is running..');
});
```

In xshell (command prompt) displaying message

```
"ubuntu@ip-***-**-*-***:~/admin/$ node app.js
Node server is running.."
```

Now i want to see Hello world in browser,How can i do this ?

For example my hostname is 11.111.11.111
and ip (displaying by xshell) is 222-22-2-222
And in ftp i put my code inside following directory
/home/ubuntu/admin

I just want to know that how can i see output in browser ? I tried with following urls but not worked for me
(hostname)

```
**.***.**.***/admin:3000
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be working:
`**.***.**.***:3000/admin`

Note that the requests follow the format: 
`host:port/directory`